# Scaling C# database application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I apologize if this question is a bit nebulous.

I am writing a C# application which does data manipulation against a SQL Server database.  For a group of items, I read data for each item, do calculations on the data, then write the results to the database.

The problem I am having is that the application starts to slow down relative to the time it takes to process each item when the number of items to be processed increases.

I am trying to be very careful as far as freeing memory for allocated objects as I am through with them.  I want to have nothing hanging around from the processing of one item when I start the processing for the next item.  I make use of "using" structures for data tables and the BulkCopy class to try to force memory cleanup.

Yet, I start to get geometrically increasing run times per item the more items I try to process in one invocation of the program.

My program is a WinForms app.  I don't seem to be eating up the server's memory with what I am doing.  I am trying to make the processing of each item isolated from the processing of all other items, to make sure it would not matter how many items I process in each invocation of the application.

Has anyone seen this behavior in their applications and know what to look for to correct this?

Comment: We need to see some code.

Comment: Post the code so we can see if the C# code can be converted to a Stored Procedure. That might speed up things.

Comment: There are tons of things you can do, especially since it is a WinForms app. You can use the `TaskParallel` library, you can optimize your SQL, you can probably refactor your code to be more performant, but, without seeing any of the code, we can't really help you.

Comment: Depending on exactly what processing you're doing, you might want to look at embedding a dll directly in SQL so you can pipe the data straight in and out.  That's quite a broad topic though, and not one to start from scratch on Stack Overflow...

Comment: You might want to look at deferring the SQL updates until you're done with all your data item processing (which in turn could possibly be sped up via multithreading). When executing the SQL, make sure it's transactioned. Hoping the combination of the 2 will help...

Comment: I am using the BulkCopy class do to my database writes.  It is supposed to have its own self contained transaction for each invocation.  Is there some trick to this that I could be missing.

Comment: There is too much data being produced to wait until the end to write it all out at once.

Comment: I suspect index fragmentation.  If you shut the program down and restart does it suddenly get fast again?

Comment: Geometrically increasing? This is similar to the Cartesian product of two tables. Run activity monitor, check, if some query is running too long.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can be watchful for - if you're using "using" statements - are you making sure that you're not keeping your connection open while manipulating your objects? Best to make sure you get your data from the database, close the connection, do your manipulation and then send the data back.

Are you using stored procedures for fetching/sending complex objects? You can also experiment with doing some of you data manipulation inside of the stored procedure or in functions called from them - you do NOT want to offload your entire business classes to the database, but you can do some of it there, depending on what you're doing.

Make sure your data structure is optimized as well (primary key indices, foreign keys, triggers etc. you can get some scripts from http://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/ to check the optimization of your database.

As mentioned above, try using some parallel/asynchronous patterns to divy up your work - await/async is very helpful for this, especially if you want to have calculations while also sending previous data back to the server.

Comment: I am closing and reopening connections every time I can.  I open a connection, read the data, close the connection, then do my calculations.  Any references to how to implement await/async would be appreciated.  My database has solid primary keys to use to retrieve the data.  What still gets me is that I would think any inefficiencies in my code would affect the processing speed regardless of how many cycles I am trying to perform.

Comment: The amount of data I am having to heave around requires that I cannot get all of the data for all items at once.  I have to make successive trips back to the source database.  But I am opening and closing the connection for each trip.

Comment: I am using straight SQL queries to retrieve the data.  This program will be used on various customers' servers.  Each customer will have their own data model to work from.  It would be painful to have to keep stored procedures current on all of their servers.  I am not sure I would even be allowed to put stored procedures on their systems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input.  I checked the issues of opening/closing connections, etc. to see that I was being tidy.  The thing that really helped was removing the primary keys on the destination data table. These were setup relative to what an end user would require, but they really gummed up the speed of data inserts.  A heads up to folks to think about database constraints for updating data vs. using the data.

Also, found performance issues in selecting with a filter from an in memory DataTable.  Somehow what I was doing get bogged down with a larger number of rows (30,000).  I realized that I was mishandling the data and did not really need to do this.  But it did show me the need to micro-test each step of my logic when trying to drag so much data around.